# Package puppeteer don't work properly (centos 7)

Tags: node.js, centos, puppeteer, centos7, chromium

I used the package puppeteer to generate pdf in nodejs in local developement i use lubuntu 18.04 and every thing works great but in production after deploying the code in centos 7 it works sometimes but the majority of time it doesn't work.
i installed necessary packages of chromium using this command:

```
sudo yum install pango.x86_64 libXcomposite.x86_64 libXcursor.x86_64 libXdamage.x86_64 libXext.x86_64 libXi.x86_64 libXtst.x86_64 cups-libs.x86_64 libXScrnSaver.x86_64 libXrandr.x86_64 GConf2.x86_64 alsa-lib.x86_64 atk.x86_64 gtk3.x86_64 ipa-gothic-fonts xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-utils xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-misc
```

I added the argument `{args:['--no-sandbox']}` but the same problem.
This is my code :

```
const generator = (data, fileName, prepa) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });

      const page = await browser.newPage();

      let content;
      if (prepa === true) {
        content = templateCarnetPrepa(data);
      } else {
        content = templateCarnet(data);
      }

      await page.setContent(content);
      await page.addStyleTag({ path: "./bootstrap.min.css" });

      await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
      await page.pdf({
        path: `./${ENV.MEDIA_STORAGE}/carnet/${fileName}.pdf`,
        format: "A4",
        margin: { top: 20, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20 },
        printBackground: true,
      });
      await browser.close();
      //process.exit()
      resolve(0);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(e);
    }
  });
```

Does any one have a solution to this problem ?

Comment: maybe a dumb question but had you `yum update nss -y` after installing the dependencies? the fact it works inconsistently suggests the dependencies are still not totally fine.

Comment: @theDavidBarton yes i made update for nss but the problem still